# ngStyle applying to all elements in ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor, ng-style

I am attempting to configure this Angular/Html/JS so that the elements begin to have a blue background when counter >= 5

```
<p
  *ngFor="let log of clickLog"
  [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: counter >= 5 ? 'blue' : 'transparent'}">
  {{ log }}
</p>
```

when the counter is <= 4, all elements have no styling, as intended. The problem is: once the counter hits 5, ALL elements take on the blue background. My intention is that only elements 5+ have the background.

Edit: I am aware that I can use an index value from the ngFor-loop as an alternative solution. I am specifically curious why this approach does not work.

Comment: See if it works for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-kjjdkn

Comment: `this.counter` is not part of your `this.clicklog`, which you're looping. So `this.counter` is true for all the items in `this.clicklog` getting applied that style.

Comment: Thank you @chaitanya. This is what I was looking for. While I had found alternative methods, like using an index as suggested in one of the answers below, my goal was to run the condition based on a value in my typescript file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The binding of **`counter`** inside **`[ngStyle]`** is called [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property) which mean Angular will observe and evaluate all **`[ngStyle]`** in your **`<p>`** tag again and again whenever it dectects changes from **`counter`** value.(your misunderstanding is that **`counter`** value is evaluated and scoped in each loop)

That why when **`counter`** become higher than 5, all **`[ngStyle]`** is evaluated again and have the style **`backgroundColor:blue`**. Therefore currently there is no way to archive what you want with only one property **`counter`** from your TS file.

I would suggest using ***ngFor** 's index which it's value is evaluated and scoped in each loop:

```
<p
  *ngFor="let log of clickLog; let indexOfElement = index;"
  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (indexOfElement >= 4) ? 'blue' : ''}">
  {{ log }}
</p>
```

Comment: he needs to check the counter value and he needs to give style to the elements having index greater than counter.

Comment: As i said, there no way to control it with only one propery from TS using `[ngStyle]`, i dont see any reason to not use index since the logic is to change style of items that have length higher than 5

Comment: Even I given answer using index. Along with index he needs to check `counter` value which is not part of `clickLog`

Comment: As I see the ideal he want is to give the `couter` inside each `[ngStyle]` a scoped value that evaluate only one time which is impossible due to Angular data binding mechanism, you dont need include `counter` for the logic he want if  `index` is used

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
<p
  *ngFor="let log of clickLog; let counter = index"
  [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: counter >=5 ? 'blue' : 'transparent'}">
  {{ log }}
</p>
```

Alternatively you could do it with CSS if it was always 5 with [nth-child(n+5)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: This is technically correct, but my goal is to check the condition using a value from my typescript class.

Answer (score 1):

Once give a try. I didn't tried, but I think it'll work.

```
<p *ngFor="let log of clickLog; let i=index;" 
  [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: (counter >=5 && i>=4) ?  'blue':'transparent'}">
  {{ log }}
</p>
```